# Java FileOutputStream Write not working

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

I followed the tutorial here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/

And have implemented the following code as an example:

```
File scoreFile = new File("score.txt");
if(!scoreFile.exists()) {
   scoreFile.createNewFile();
} 
oFile = new FileOutputStream(scoreFile, false);
oFile.write("Score = 1".getBytes());
oFile.flush();
oFile.close();
```

But nothing is being written to the file score.txt.

EDIT: The whole function is given below:

```
// Set win or loose to score.dat.
    public void setScore(boolean won, boolean reset){
        out.println("setScore()");
        long timePassed = (timeEnd - timeStart)/1000; // Seconds passed.
        double[] prevScore = getScore(); // get previous score (Won, Lost).
        // Create a writer to edit the file.
        File scoreFile = new File("score.txt");
        if(!scoreFile.exists()) {
            try {
                scoreFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        if(!reset){
            if(won){
                // Add time to Win values.
                prevScore[0] += timePassed;
            }
            else{
                // Add time to Lost values.
                prevScore[1] += timePassed;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream oFile = new FileOutputStream(scoreFile, false);
                // Write new score.
                byte[] contentBytes = (String.valueOf(prevScore[0]+" "+prevScore[1])).getBytes();
                oFile.write("Bye".getBytes());
                oFile.flush();
                oFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            // If battle ended, delete the scores.
            FileOutputStream oFile;
            try {
                if(!scoreFile.exists()) {
                    scoreFile.createNewFile();
                } 
                oFile = new FileOutputStream(scoreFile, false);
                oFile.write("Error".getBytes());
                oFile.flush();
                oFile.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I know where the file is created because I can see that it creates the file, but it doesn't populate it with any text.

Comment: Are you looking at the good score.txt file? Try sysout the scoreFile.getAbsolutePath() to be sure. If this does not solve your issue post an SSCCE (http://sscce.org)

Comment: Why are you taking contentBytes and simply throwing it away?

Answer (score 3):

That piece of code works for me... Are you looking at the right place? You can try to change the filename to `"C:\\score.txt"` for example to make sure you look in the right folder.

Comment: Could you look at the edited question and suggest anything that may fix the code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The code definitely works.(assuming you've declared oFile) .Score.txt must be in your working directory